# Странная ошибка при компиляции

Tags: c++, codeblocks

При компиляции выдает ошибку: `error: declaration of 'operator>>' as non-function`

Вот код заголовочного файла:

```
#ifndef STRING_H
#define STRING_H

#include <iostream>


class String
{
    private:
        char *p;
        int size;
    public:
        String();
        String(char* str);
        String(const String &obj);
        ~String() {delete [] p;}
        friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const String &obj);
        friend std::istream &operator>>(std::isteram &is, const String &obj);
        String operator+(const String &obj);
        String operator-(const String &obj);
        friend int str_cmp(const String &obj_1, const String &obj_2);
        char get_ch(int pos);
};

#endif // STRING_H
```

В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

банальная опечатка - `isteram`, а надо `istream`, будьте внимательнее